# G9 DL380 with no smart array controller

Tags: hpe

I'm planning on running Ceph cluster on HPE G9 DL380 servers. As I have used the servers for Ceph cluster, there is no RAID requirement for the servers.
My question is, do I need to purchase smart array controller (like Smart Array P440ar Controller, etc.) even if I need NO RAID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it has X4 SATA ports (1 and 2).
If you need guide for Removing and Replacing HP Smart Array Controller you can follow official hp site https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=a00044492en_us&docLocale=en_US

or following this istructions:

HP smart array controller removal instructions

1
Press the power button to put the server in standby.

2
Disconnect the power cord from the server.

3
Remove the access panel.

4
Disconnect the cables from the controller.

5
Loosen the three captive thumbscrews that secure the controller to the chassis pan.

6
Pull up on the blue tab to disconnect the controller from the system board and then lift to remove.

7
Flex the left side of the controller baffle to disengage the retaining tabs and move the baffle to the right and lift it off of the controller.

HP smart array controller replacement instructions

1
Hook the retaining tabs on the right side of the baffle onto the controller heatsink as shown.

2
Flex the left side of the baffle and lower it into place so that the tabs engage the heatsink.

3
Align the holes in the controller with the guide pins on the chassis pan and lower it into place and press the controller down at the touch point until it is fully seated.

4
Tighten the three screws.

5
Connect the cables to the controller.

Comment: wouldn't hurt explicitly spelling out the *why* as well, even if that link (currently, possibly not so much the next time they break all links) explains the *how*